# When else has a certain character died? (Wheel of Time, minor spoiler)

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

Now, this is probably a stupid question, but in a Memory of Light Birgitte mentions to Mat that the time he got hung was not the time he "died and lived again," but that he does not remember it.

Now, I'm guessing he doesn't remember because it happened because he had the dagger, so is there a time after the second book but before he gets cured (I really don't remember which book that was in) that he died and lived again? (I'm even going out on a limb by not assuming the aelfinn's prophecy referred to the future)

Answer (score 14):

Mat was killed in the attack on Rahvin in Caemlyn, near the end of *The Fires of Heaven*. Most of Rand's party is killed by Rahvin's channeling. When Rand later balefires Rahvin, it undoes those deaths, including Mat's.

It has been largely accepted for a long time that this event fulfilled the "dying and living again" part of the prophecy; he never actually died when he was hung, he was simply "near death". This was eventually confirmed directly by Jordan at a convention, as explained [here.](http://wotfaq.dragonmount.com/book/export/html/75)

> It was much less clear what this meant in terms of The Horn of Valere, but Birgitte's comments seem to point to this incident as breaking Mat's connection to the Horn.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note, I also remember when Mat and Rand were at Rhuidean and the darkhounds attacked. I seem to remember that the saliva was poisonous and a darkhound was breaking down the door where Mat was. Some of the saliva landed on Mat and when he 'remembers' the encounter, he seems to recall he died but it's all vague for him.  Rand eventually "balefires" the dog, so that any thing the dog had done earlier now did not happen (sorry for the tenses, but the logic seems to still stand).  Therefore, one can assume that Mat "died" and came back once the dog had been balefired.

Comment: You're referring to The Fires of Heaven, Chapter 6. I do not recall anything implying Mat died then.

Comment: he didn't die then; IIRC Moiraine comments that he "should be" dead because the Shadowhound slobbered on him, but he merely has a mild rash.

Answer (score -1):

No he also died when Rand fought Ravhin, but was brought back to life when Rand fought Ravhin, but he was brought back to life when Rand killed Ravhin because Rand was drawing all the saidin he could hold, so the effect went back  in time quite a few minutes.

Comment: Is this meant as a comment on someone else’s post?