# A character is claimed to have died over the course of the series. When did that happen?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When else has Mat died? (Wheel of Time, minor spoiler)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30530/when-else-has-mat-died-wheel-of-time-minor-spoiler)

In A Memory of Light, it is revealed that:

> The Horn of Valere is no longer bound to Mat, due to him having died.

However, one of the Heroes of the Horn (Artur Hawkwing himself, if I recall correctly) corrects him and indicates:

> Mat's death from hanging in Rhuidean was not the death that severed the connection to the Horn of Valere.

If that wasn't when it happened, when did it?  Did he die twice?

Comment: I had always assumed that the hanging was his death, because Rand explicitly revived him. Maybe the memories he got from the Foxes, including memories of dying, counted as having died? Could that have broken his connection to the Horn?

Comment: Also, please try to write less spoiler-iffic titles in the future! A post can be avoided, but it's hard to avoid reading a title in the list of questions.

Comment: @rsegal I was trying to come up with a less spoiler-y title, but was having trouble finding one that was appropriate without revealing much.  I left it because saying the character in question died is not nearly the spoiler it appears to be, given the specifics in the series. Thank you for your edit, though, it handles it nicely.

Comment: @NikolaiDante Definite duplicate... missed that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was when Rahvin killed him during the attack on Caemlyn at the end of The Fires of Heaven.  During the ambush, Mat, Aviendha, and Asmodean were all killed by lightning from Rahvin.  At the end of the fight Rand balefired Rahvin, undoing his actions and bringing those three back to life.

From my CoT signing report:

**Tim Kington**
My friend Josh and I had been talking about how Rand and Mat spent a week in Rhuidean, and so he asked how long Mat was hanging.

**Robert Jordan**
Long enough.

**Josh**
Long enough for what?

**ROBERT JORDAN**
Long enough to be ALMOST dead.

http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=161

Comment: Woah... that could totally be it. The nature of the Balefire ret-gone is still confusing at best.

Comment: Interesting.  I thought that balefire meant that events erased never actually happened, though. In the end, shields woven by Aes Sedai moments before they were killed by balefire never existed, causing the other Aes Sedai protected by those shields to fall victim to weaves that were previously blocked. It seems odd that the Horn would "remember" things removed from the pattern in such a fashion.

Comment: I agree about the horn "remembering" being weird.  It does fit well with "To die and live again, and live once more a part of what was!" - he relived that half-hour or so a second time.