# How was Olver able to do it?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

In aMoL,

> Olver blows the Horn of Valere and the pattern spits out all the heroes to come and save the day.

But, he really shouldn't have been able to do it since Mat is supposed to be the designated wielder of said artefact. What am I missing?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30530/when-else-has-mat-died-wheel-of-time-minor-spoiler/30533#30533

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When Rand attacked Caemlyn, Mat was killed by Rahvin, breaking his connection to the Horn.  He was brought back by Rand balefiring Rahvin, but apparently anyone could have blown the Horn after that.

Comment: So, nobody knew about this? Hmm, it would've, IMHO, been neater to have had Faile blow it considering that she was one of the Hunters of the Horn.

Comment: Jordan had clearly been setting Olver up for something big the entire series.

Answer (score 2):

Mat's connection to the horn was severed, because he died and was brought back to life. I interpreted his comment about dying to be referring to the scene in Rhuidean, when he was hung from the tree.

Comment: And also in the rand vs. Rahvin balefire incident.

Comment: It is definitely the balefire incident and not the tree. From AMOL Ch. 39 where Mat discusses the link breaking with the heroes: "Not the tree, Gambler," Hawkwing said. "Another moment, one that you cannot remember."

Answer (score 0):

I understand the reasoning - however. Balefire erases the actions of the one struck - if Mat was "brought back to life", it means he never died. Therefore he was never severed from the horn. Yeah, its a fantasy novel, and one can't expect perfect logic. Nonetheless, this has always seemed a bit ridiculous.